# Is anger and defensiveness to criticism innate or acquired?

Tags: genetics, thought, environmental-psychology

Criticism is defined, according to the [lexico.com](https://www.lexico.com/definition/criticism) dictionary, as

> The **expression of disapproval** of someone or something on the basis of
> perceived faults or mistakes.

In general, there can be two types of responses for a criticism by receiving party. One is changing self, which is the primary intention of criticism. Another is to becoming sensitive to the criticism in negative way. It is [believed by psychologists](https://www.karrass.com/en/blog/criticism-and-its-negative-effects) that most humans choose second one.

> Most psychologists agree that criticism does not lead people to change
> behavior. Instead it **creates anger and defensiveness** on the part of
> the person criticized.  Communication between the parties is shackled,
> and positive relationships impeded.

Is such negative sensitiveness, especially anger and defensiveness, in a person due to criticism innate (genetic) or acquired after birth (environment)?

*Note*: Assume that the criticism is a constructive one and the defensiveness is not needed in this context.